# C#: Non-Winforms way to exit the application?

Tags: c#, .net

I know about Application.Exit() but what if I'm not in a windows forms application but in a simple class library, how do I signal for the application to exit?

Comment: Should a class library be exiting an application?

Comment: Of course, what if it is a set of Mediators which form the Business Logic Layer for an application?

Comment: Exiting an application is business logic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Environment.Exit() -- but why would you ever want to do this from a method in a class library?

Comment: Forgot about this. It's probably better than my P/Invoke suggestions.

Comment: Mind you - this requires extra security privileges (really wish it didn't...) - specifically, executing unmanaged code.

Answer (score 3):

P/Invoke [ExitProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682658(VS.85).aspx), perhaps. Or if you're really in a hurry, [TerminateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Is there no .NET BCL way to do this?!!